# In Atom editor, the number spacing got WIDE and regular text spacing SHRINKED

Tags: fonts, atom-editor

Atom editor font got scrambled.
The spaces in the text SHRANK (there is a space between 'var' and 'port'), 
And the spacing inside numbers, got hugely wide.
[image: screen shot from atom]

Its all around, not just file editing tabs,

[image: screen shot from atom's configuration]
Did anyone got into such issues?

Answer (score 0):

ok. apparently 'roboto mono' font couse this for some reason...
it wasn't like this at start...
I just remove it, and all ok now.

[image: roboto mono]